# Best way to block / show "Working..." notification when calling a time-consuming Java command externally

Tags: java, php, ajax, shell, blocking

I have a Java class which can be called from shell. (via "java [command][options]") The class takes in a set of parameters and outputs a MIDI file.

What I want to do is set up a simple webapp which reads from a pre-determined directory which will always contain 3 MIDI files (only!). A visitor to the webapp is presented with these three files, and has to choose one which s/he thinks is the best (submit a form). The webapp will use that information to generate a set of 3 new MIDI files using the Java class, while recording info to a log file and moving the old files to an archive directory.

The 3 things which I'm not sure about are:

1) What web language would be best for this? I plan to make this into a full-fledged app at some point, but the dependency on Java makes me think using Servlets is the way to go. However, would PHP or Rails (for ex.) be easier? Is it okay/possible to call Java via a shell command from PHP or other languages?

2) Generating the MIDI takes some time, so I want some sort of loading bar or "Waiting..." notice to appear on screen after the user submits the form. Basically I want the app to block and show that notice while the shell command executes, and render the new page when the command finishes and the new MIDIs are generated. Is there any example that I can follow to achieve this (AJAX with PHP or Servlets would be nice)?

3) When more than one person is on the website, and one person submits the form (and starts the MIDI generation), then I want everyone to get a loading notice or at least trigger some action. Is there a clean way to do this?

Thanks to any responses!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your questions are a bit open ended, you should try to focus your questions a little more in the future. I'll try to give you some guidance though.

**1)** I wouldn't necessarily say there is a "best" way to do this, as you could easily use any number of solutions. Do you have any experience with building a web application? If so, use what you're familiar with. If not, maybe choose a framework in a language you're comfortable in, or explore creating a server from scratch in that language.

**2)** and **3)** concern implementing features, again, you could do it in a number of ways. Ajax is definitely one way of approaching both these problems. I think you should do a little more research about the technologies you plan on using so you're more aware of their capabilities. Try creating a solution using Ajax and see how that works.

Comment: I realize, and I am not very experienced with web applications. I think I will try your suggestion of Ajax and see where that takes me-after all this is not a production app so I'm not afraid to have a hacky/messy solution at first.

Comment: Don't be afraid to fail, that's how you learn! Programming well is all about iteration. If your first solution seems hacky, try again and refine your solution.

Answer (score 0):

You should provide the web user with real feedback if possible. Using a [progress bar](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Progressbar), you could use AJAX to call a servlet or any server side script that checks on the status of the program and get a percentage complete.

There would be two different operations here. The first that you mention would be to start processing the MIDI. The second operation would be to check the status of the application. This second is even more important if you (as it seems like you are saying) can only run one process at a time.

One idea you could consider is emailing the user a link to the final files after you are done processing. If it is going to take a long time for each user, and you have many users, it could that ages for a webpage to ever respond to the user. That's a terrible idea and most users will find that unacceptable. An alternative delivery method such as email, may be more palatable.

Comment: Actually, this is for research purposes; I don't really care about users for now, people can just come on the site and rate MIDIs. I just want to make sure that when someone visits the page, it's not possible to initiate MIDI processing while MIDIs are being generated already. Perhaps I could generate a token when the MIDI generation starts and delete it when it's done? And once the token is there, if someone else tries to generate MIDIs, they are either rejected or put into a queue? Ahhh, I don't know.